# how to add compile-time metadata/behavior to specific function

Tags: c++, embedded

My codebase is C++ on NXP ARM M4 with custom C++ RTOS.

There exists a certain function, `DWB()` aka `DangerWillRobinson()`, that if called *could* have unexpected side-effects (which are valid when it's used correctly).

`DWB()` could be called in a very deeply nested manner as in
`A()->B()->C()->D()->...->DWB()`

I want author of any functions that, directly or indirectly, call `DWB()` to be aware that `DWB()` is called **and** I want to force them to acknowledge that they know `DWB()` is called.

I know this could be accomplished by parsing the linker's generated call-trees using Python but I'd much prefer this to be a compile-time error thing.

Here's how I'd like this to work:

```
void A()
{
    B();
}
```

Author goes to compile:

> ERROR: DWB() is called. Please acknowledge.

Author then thinks about side-effects of calling `DWB()` and finds no issues.

```
void A()
{
    // some macro-thing ... ?
    B();
}
```

If possible, I do not want this to be a runtime check. I think in theory, this is possible. If `Base` is inherited, I would like all possible classes' call-trees to be considered; it's ok if none of them are even instantiated but not ideal.

**QUESTION**

Is this compile-time metadata/behavior of a function possible?

Comment: A bit more weak instrument would be to mark the `DWB()` function itself as deprecated. If the authors are aware, they shouldn't ignore such warnings.

Comment: BTW, why not trying to fix the unwanted side effects of `DWB()` in 1st place? And be it throwing assertions (or exceptions) for unwanted bahavior in the function. I well know, refactoring such stuff is a though job.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because they're valid when the function is used correctly; this is embedded system.

Comment: _" when the function is used correctly"_ `assert()` sanitiy checks in `DWB()` is what you want to have. Ensure the input parameters correctness from inside the function implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's not about the input parameters to the function as it has no input parameters.

Comment: So you need to `assert()` consitency of global values, much like the same thing. Use `assert()` if you know what are the conditions that the function is called correctly. That's all of it's purpose. These kind of bugs can't be caught at compile time, may be using an additional SCA tool (one of the commercial products playing at the high level).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `DWB()` is not the issue. It's not gonna change. I want the caller(s) to be aware that they're calling it and acknowledge to the compiler. `DWB()` is actually `Sleep()` in my cooperative RTOS. Whenever I mention "cooperative RTOS", people here just ignore the "cooperative" part or try to shoe-horn their preemptive OS knowledge into my question so I've tried to obfuscate it.

Comment: Well, I wrote my answer just from the information you gave in your question and some of your comments. If you have a function that can be called in a non intended way, it might not be needed at all.

Comment: Would such a thing even be useful? I'm thinking of functions very far removed from the direct call to `DWB()`. Take it to the extreme and think about the `main()` function. If `DWB()` is called at all, it is called indirectly from `main()`. Is the author of `main()` supposed to verify every call to `DWB()`? Is the author of `main()` going to just figure it's not worth the effort and flag "OK to call DWB" without thinking about side-effects? (If `main()` is too far removed to worry about this, how would you demarcate "too far removed"?) There's probably a better strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this compile-time metadata/behavior of a function possible?

No, it isn't. There might be some configurable SCA tools available (consider a commercial high level one), but not with plain c-preprocessing or meta-template-programming magic.

---

> I want author of any functions that, directly or indirectly, call `DWB()` to be aware that `DWB()` is called and I want to force them to acknowledge that they know `DWB()` is called.

The least intrusive way to do that is to mark the `DWB()` function [`[[deprecated]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated).

I just suppose you prefer to factor out such error prone function in a midterm roadmap, and replace it with something more stable.

The most quick way in case you are sure what all the conditions of a correct `DWB()` call are is to apply a bunch of `assert()` calls at the start of that function.

There might come up complaints from fellow developers, which are trying to use that function incorrectly. Give them best advice as you can in the assertion messages.